# Remove comma in quoted string - no vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this string in cell A1

```
"A","Agilent Technologies, Inc.",60.73
```

I'm trying to figure out a formula to get this result in cell B1

```
A,Agilent Technologies Inc.,60.73
```

Although I have a solution with VBA, I was wondering if there's a way do that without VBA.
So only using excel formulas.
Preferably a single cell formula.

The easy part is getting rid of the quotes (that's easy).
The hard part is getting rid of the comma in "Agilent Technologies, Inc." because that's the field delimiter.

ps: I can't just remove the 2nd comma, because the number of fields can differ.
For example, the name "Agilent Technologies, Inc." could be the 3rd of 4th field.

Another example would be

```
"C=F","Corn Futures,Dec-2017,Composite",394.25
```

Which needs to become

```
C=F,Corn Futures Dec-2017 Composite,394.25
```

**Rule/Logic**
The field delimiter is a comma.
Any comma that is found within a quoted string (between `"` and `"`) should be removed.
The comma's that serve as field delimiter must remain.
Finally, the quotes (`"`) must be removed too.

Comment: If there is always a space before the comma you want to replace, it should be pretty straightforward?

Comment: @bioschaf omg, indeed. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  Solution is =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;", ";" ");"""";"")

Comment: Hmm... got another example where that formula doesn't work (will addit it to the question).  "C=F","Corn Futures,Dec-2017,Composite",394.25

Comment: In order for us to suggest a solution, you need to provide a few rows of data and mock up the desired results for each row. Include all possible scenarios in your data sample and explain the logic how each record arrives at its respective result. It does not help if you start with a simple example and then post comments that another data example has a different logic. So, post all permutations of your data and explain in simple words what the processing logic is that leads to your desired result. Edit your question to provide that information. Do NOT post that in a comment.

Comment: Ok, can you check if every comma that needs to stay has a Quote in front of it? If so, replace every occurence of ", with a special char that doesn't appear in your data (e.g. $). Then, remove all remaining comma. Last step will replace all $ again with ",

Comment: What is the logic? In the first example you want the comma removed in front of the word "Inc". In the second example you want the comma remove in front of the word "composite". What is the rule? We can help you create a formula, but we need a framework for the logic, not just a few disconnected examples that only a human brain can make sense of. What rule/logic do you want to apply?

Comment: Added Logic/Rule to the question. The 2 examples provided are the only 2 permutations in the data as far as I can see.

Comment: There's a formula solution if the non-removed commas (field separators) always come directly after a double-quotes. i.e. `",`. In that case we can remove commas that are not preceded by `"`. Does that apply to your data? p.s. It could be also be *preceded or followed by `"`*

Comment: @A.S.H Unfortunately that's not the case. The example data is a short version for demonstration purposes. The actual data can contain many more than 3 fields, which all can be either floating point numbers, or quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a space before a comma in a quoted string, then

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;", ";" ");"""";"")
```

will work.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use any formula, just use the Find and Replace function (Ctrl+H), and replace all `"` with blank.

Comment: I need it to be a formula.